# Division of random variables java

Tags: java, integer, division

I have a weird logic error in my code which doesn't allow me to divide my variables.

```
if (cWeapon == soulSteeler) {
    lifeTake = damageDealt / 10;
    lifeTake += health;
}
```

This is where I try to divide the damage dealt and add it to my health.  I change my `int` to `float` on `lifeTake damageDealt` and `health` because I knew that I could get some decimals.

When I do this nothing happens.

Comment: If damageDealt is an int < 10 you'll get zero back.  It's important to understand how integer division works.  Cast it to a float/double and you'll do better.

Comment: If you are updating your `health`, it should probably be `health += lifeTake`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
// I assume these are not Strings.  If they are, compare using equals
if (cWeapon == soulSteeler) {
    lifeTake = damageDealt/10.0;
    lifeTake += health;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `lifeTake = (damageDealt/10.0) + health;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Like Duffymo said, It is likely that damageDealt is an integer less than 10 which would make damageDealt/10 always 0.  To fix this, change 10 to 10.0, or cast it as a float or a double.  Also cast damageDealt as a double or a float to give you the correct result.  Also make sure that lifeTake is a float/double or else you will suffer from the same data narrowing.

Comment: I don't recall needed a second.  It doesn't seem helpful or necessary to repeat what I said.